# Formula needed: Sort array to array-"snaked"

Tags: algorithm, arrays, sorting

After the you guys helped me out so gracefully last time, here is another tricky array sorter for you.

I have the following array:

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

I use it for some visual stuff and render it like this:

```
1   2  3  4

5   6  7  8

9  10 11 12

13 14 15 16
```

Now I want to sort the array to have a "snake" later:

```
// rearrange the array according to this schema
1   2  3 4

12 13 14 5

11 16 15 6

10  9  8 7

// the original array should look like this
a = [1,2,3,4,12,13,14,5,11,16,15,6,10,9,8,7]
```

Now I'm looking for a smart formula / smart loop to do that

```
ticker = 0;
rows = 4; // can be n
cols = 4; // can be n
originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
newArray = [];

while(ticker < originalArray.length)
{
    //do the magic here
    ticker++;
}
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Another homework assignment that you let others do :)

Comment: Actually, I already have I made with 75(!) lines of code. I'm wondering if there is a smarter way...

Comment: There probably is a smarter way to do this. I would say around 10 lines of code inside the loop would be a good goal.

Comment: Yap, I'll give it another shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bored, so I made a python version for you with 9 lines of code inside the loop.

```
ticker = 0
rows = 4
cols = 4
originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
newArray = [None] * (rows * cols)
row = 0
col = 0
dir_x = 1
dir_y = 0
taken = {}

while (ticker < len(originalArray)):
    newArray[row * cols + col] = originalArray[ticker]
    taken[row * cols + col] = True

    if col + dir_x >= cols or row + dir_y >= rows or col + dir_x < 0:
        dir_x, dir_y = -dir_y, dir_x
    elif ((row + dir_y) * cols + col + dir_x) in taken:
        dir_x, dir_y = -dir_y, dir_x

    row += dir_y
    col += dir_x    
    ticker += 1

print newArray
```

Comment: Works like a charm. For me there are a few lines more since I had to solve the multiple assignment (which seam to be pretty handy in python btw). Also you could put the else condition in the if to save one more line. Yeah, I know... :) However, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can index into the snake coil directly if you recall that

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n*(n+1)/2
m^2 + m - k = 0  =>  m - (-1+sqrt(1+4*k))/2
```

and look at the pattern of the coils.  (I'll leave it as a hint for the time being--you could also use that `n^2 = (n-1)^2 + (2*n+1)` with reverse-indexing, or a variety of other things to solve the problem.)

When translating to code, it's not really any shorter than Tuomas' solution if all you want to do is fill the matrix, however.