# Multidimension array sorting (snake)

Tags: java, sorting

I could find answer in google, so maybe you can suggest me something.

**The task is:**

1. Creat multidimension array with random digits - **Done**;
2. Sort multidimension array - **Done**;
3. Sort multidimension array (snake) - ***Not Done;***

So, for eample:

We have:
**Sorted array:**

- [5][2][4]
- [1][3][6]
- [9][7][8]

How can we sort it in snake type:

- [1][2][3]
- [4][5][6]
- [7][8][9]

There's a code with two DONE tasks:

```
public class Snake {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int line = 3;
int column = 3;

new Snake().sort(line, column);

}

Random rnd;

public void sort(int line, int column) {
rnd = new Random();
int temp = 0;
int[][] arr = new int[line][column];
System.out.println("Unsorted array:");
for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(50) + 1;
    System.out.print("[" + arr[i][j] + "]");

    }
    System.out.println();
}

for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < column - 1; k++) {
        if (arr[j][k] > arr[j][k + 1]) {
        temp = arr[j][k];
        arr[j][k] = arr[j][k + 1];
        arr[j][k + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    }
}

System.out.println("Sorted array:");
for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
    System.out.print("[" + arr[i][j] + "]");
    }
    System.out.println();

}

}
```

}

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464469/formula-needed-sort-array-to-array-snaked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some ShearSort-like algorithm or [ShearSort](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~atk/Java/Sorting/ShearSortAlgorithm.java) itself

More on that:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9781593271824/sorting-algorithms/shear_sort

http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/twodim/shear/shearsorten.htm